# How to hide push notification in ios?

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications

How to hide push notification in ios? I need to convert push notification to local notification. what should be the structure of payload for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html
You can refer the above link to Know about the payload of push notification.
For not showing push notification you need to pass the payload without alert. If you want a silent notification set Content-available as 1. It'll help.

Eg:

```
{"aps" : {

        "content-available" : 1
    },

    "YourData":""
}
```

Comment: once we send without alert notification extension do not called. do you have by solution for that

Answer (score 1):

structure of payload for hide the push notification is..

**This Show notification**

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : "Message received from Bob"
        "badge" : 5,
    },
    "acme1" : "bar",
    "acme2" : [ "bang",  "whiz" ]
}
```

**This one hide your notification**

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "badge" : 5,
    },
    "acme1" : "bar",
    "acme2" : [ "bang",  "whiz" ]
}
```